# Is it possible to create a 'permanent' table from stored procedure results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, procedure

I am  pretty new to SQL. But really want to learn as much as possible. However, I really have something I need to do for work (kind of got thrown into it). But I keep running into road blocks. I need to create a table that always has update information from this stored procedure I created. I initially tried joining tables, etc but just couldn't get the exact data I needed. The best way I have found so far to accomplish at least gathering the correct data is to use this stored procedure. However, here comes another road block; putting it in a table. The reason I need a table is because an external application (one that is being developed for our location) needs to have this table to view certain information. It will look at this table several times a day because the data may change. I would greatly appreciate any help or advice that may lead me to the solution I need. Thank you in advance.

Here is the stored procedure I have now. (I would of loved to had been able to just use this to create a view but of course I can't because of the variable declaration)

```
    DECLARE @now DATETIME
    SET @now = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),108)


    IF @now BETWEEN '06:40:00' AND '14:39:59'
    SELECT t.ProductionDate, t.Shift, t.LineNumber, t.Cart, t.CavityPosition,   t.ProgramNumber, t.PartNumber,t.Cavity
    FROM tblTransactionDetail t
    JOIN tblLPCurrentOnline c
    on t.Cart=c.Fixture
    AND t.ProgramNumber=c.Program
    AND t.LineNumber=c.Linenumber  
    WHERE Shift = 1 and PartNumber <>''

    ELSE IF @now BETWEEN '14:40:00' AND '22:39:59'
        SELECT t.ProductionDate, t.Shift, t.LineNumber, t.Cart, t.CavityPosition, t.ProgramNumber, t.PartNumber,t.Cavity
    FROM tblTransactionDetail t
    JOIN tblLPCurrentOnline c
    on t.Cart=c.Fixture
    AND t.ProgramNumber=c.Program
    AND t.LineNumber=c.Linenumber 
    WHERE Shift = 2 AND PartNumber <>''

ELSE IF @now BETWEEN '22:40:00' AND '24:59:59' OR @now BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '06:39:59'
    SELECT  t.ProductionDate, t.Shift, t.LineNumber, t.Cart, t.CavityPosition, t.ProgramNumber, t.PartNumber,t.Cavity
 FROM tblTransactionDetail t
JOIN tblLPCurrentOnline c
on t.Cart=c.Fixture
AND t.ProgramNumber=c.Program
AND t.LineNumber=c.Linenumber 
WHERE Shift = 3 AND PartNumber <>''
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table with the results of any select by saying "INTO whereever" before the "FROM" clause.  But if the table exists you'll get an error.  So usually you make the stored procedure check to see if the table is there, drop (delete) it if it is, then run the query.  Then you have to arrange the stored procedure run before you query it if you want the data you get to be more or less "live"

Details vary depending on what product you are using, everything you write looks like function names/conventions I associate with microsoft sql server, or maybe mysql, but please say what you're using.

Also: Welcome to StackOverflow, You should tag your questions with the precise version of sql you're using; read this, it's short: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info.

Comment: I'm sorry, that would help if I would of said what I am using. It is SQL Server 2005. I see what your saying about making the stored procedure check to see if the table is there etc. But that would require something having to run the stored procedure right? I couldn't set this automatically some how? The reason I ask is because this program that is being created for us is going to look for table data. So I would want that table present and accurate when the program goes to check it. Or maybe this is not the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to have a parameter.  I haven't ever written a query like this but you can say "DATEPART(hh,GETDATE())" and "DATEPART(mm,GETDATE())" to get the hour and minute, respectively.  And you can include tests for what hour it is in your queries.

You can use that to get rid of your if statement, and the parameter.  Right now you have:

```
   WHERE Shift = 3 AND PartNumber <>''
```

Conceptually if you could say "WHERE shift = *whatever shift it is now*", that would do the trick.  In SQL, you use the CASE statement.  There are two forms; you can read about that in google, I'm going to show the "searched" form below.

If it were simply  a matter two shifts say, from midnight to 2 pm, is 1 and other times are shift 2, you'd want to know if hour < 14 or not.  You could say:

```
  WHERE shift = CASE WHEN DATEPART(hh, GETDATE()) < 14 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AND partNubmer <> ''
```

Does that make sense?  Depending when it was run, you'd either get shift = 1 OR shift = 2.

```
SELECT t.ProductionDate, t.Shift, t.LineNumber, t.Cart, t.CavityPosition,        t.ProgramNumber, t.PartNumber,t.Cavity
    FROM tblTransactionDetail t
    JOIN tblLPCurrentOnline c
    on t.Cart=c.Fixture
    AND t.ProgramNumber=c.Program
    AND t.LineNumber=c.Linenumber  
    WHERE PartNumber <>'' AND
       CASE WHEN EXPRESSION_THAT_RETURNS_TRUE_DURING_SHIFT_1 THEN 1 
       EXPRESSION_THAT_RETURNS_TRUE_DURING_SHIFT_2 THEN 2
       ELSE 3 END
```

Here, it seems like a convenient way to find out what shift it is is to ask: "What will the hour part of the current time be 20 minutes from now?"  And in sql server, to get that number, you say:

```
      SELECT DATEPART( hh, DATEADD(mi, 20, GETDATE()))
```

So, your expression can be

```
    WHERE PartNumber <>'' AND
       CASE WHEN DATEPART( hh, DATEADD(mi, 20, GETDATE())) BETWEEN 7 AND 15 THEN 1 
       WHEN DATEPART( hh, DATEADD(mi, 20, GETDATE())) BETWEEN 16 AND 22 THEN 2 -- 4pm to 11:59:59...
       ELSE 3 END
```

Hope it works.  You can try tests with taking the datepart being seconds instead of hours, ss is the symbol to use for seconds.

Comment: and that also gets rid of the need to make a table; you can put it in a view.

Comment: Yeah, this makes more sense than what I was trying to do..and also like what Paul said about not needing a stored procedure and using a CASE instead which is good because I prefer this method over a stored procedure.  Anyway, thank you so much for your time and help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see the need for a stored procedure to be created unless there is a lot of data and it takes a while to generate the data.

I would recomend changing your stored procedure slightly into a view then the view will be treated as a table.

I have not tested the query so if there are any errors I apologise:

```
CREATE VIEW REQUIREDTABLENAME
AS
    SELECT t.ProductionDate, t.Shift, t.LineNumber, t.Cart, t.CavityPosition,   t.ProgramNumber, t.PartNumber,t.Cavity  
    FROM tblTransactionDetail t  
    JOIN tblLPCurrentOnline c  
    on t.Cart=c.Fixture  
    AND t.ProgramNumber=c.Program  
    AND t.LineNumber=c.Linenumber    
    WHERE Shift = 
    case 
    when CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),108)  BETWEEN '06:40:00' AND '14:39:59' then 1 
    when CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),108)  BETWEEN '14:40:00' AND '22:39:59' then 2 
    when CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),108)  BETWEEN '22:40:00' AND '24:59:59' OR CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),108)  BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '06:39:59' then 3 
    end 
    and PartNumber <>''
```

Comment: Sorry, I started to comment back to you and never did finish. But thank you so much for your help. This is exactly what I was looking for. I really appreciate your help!!  :D